# Installing Java On Ubuntu Server

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Does anyone know the process to install java on Ubuntu?

I have my server set up with Amazon in the cloud.

I am looking to run some java servers on my server and quickly came to notice that I needed to install java.

Can someone point me in the right direction with some steps?

I have looked at some websites but in the command line when I enter sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list the file is a new file... I have read there is supposed to be an existing file. Correct?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You might have more luck on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well I'm sorry for being stupid.

Answer (score 29):

If you have terminal access, depending on the version of Java, you're looking for, it would be something like this.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I appreciate a good answer not micheal's. Accepting when I can.

Comment: On the server.  Typing that on your local machine obviously won't do anything on the server...

Comment: Also good to know, `sudo apt-cache search <search terms>` will search the `apt-get` database and provide some details.

Comment: or on server: sudo apt-get openjdk-6-jre-headless

Answer (score 2):

I use the Sun/Oracle JDK. You can download the JDK .sh file. Run it and it unpacks itself. Add the bin directory to your path and you can use it.  This doesn't require root access and you can install as many versions as you want this way.